# C# callback parameter

Tags: c#

A bit rusty in C#

I need to pass in a callback to a method:

```
void InvokeScript(string jsScript, Action<object> resultCallback);
```

In my class I have created a method to pass in to the method:

```
        public void callback(System.Action<object> resultCallback)
    { 

    }
```

Error message 1:

```
Resco.UI.IJavascriptBridge.InvokeScript(string, System.Action<object>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Error message 2:

```
cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<object>'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback should be:

```
public void callback(object value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the parameter your passing an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Action<object> myCallBack = delegate
{
// do something here
};

    InvokeScript("some string", myCallBack);
```

The method delegate needs to take an `object` and not return any value. That's what `Action<object>` means. You can use the built-in `Action` delegate as I've shown, or you can create a new method and pass it as delegate:

```
public void MyMethod(object myParameter)
{
    // do something here.
}

InvokeScript("some string", MyMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you create a method matching the signature of the `Action<object>` delegate, such as

```
public void someMethod(object parameter) { }
```

and then pass it,
or you can use a lambda:

```
InvokeScript("stuff", 
    param => { 
        Blah(param); 
        MoreBlah();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the callback should be the following:

```
void MethodName(object parameter);
```

You also may use [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) even without creating a separate method:

```
InvokeScript(
    "some string",
    p =>
    {
        // the callback's logic
    });
```